# Kendo UI Grid Hierarchy how to get children(detail) IDs by clicking one of the row field

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get all the children(detail) IDs when I click one of the row instead of using expand row.

I want to click one of the detail row and get all the detail IDs.

I tried calling detailInit from the click event but I am getting error. Either a way to get all child in an array? I am trying to get the IDs to call other service. Here is an example of a code.

```
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="grid"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                        },
                        pageSize: 6,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverSorting: true
                    },
                    height: 600,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    detailInit: detailInit,
                    dataBound: function() {
                        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            field: "FirstName",
                            title: "First Name",
                            width: "110px"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "LastName",
                            title: "Last Name",
                            width: "110px"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "Country",
                            width: "110px"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "City",
                            width: "110px"
                        },
                        {
                            field: "Title",
                           title: "Detail"
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });

            function detailInit(e) {
                $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "odata",
                        transport: {
                            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                        },
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverSorting: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: e.data.EmployeeID }
                    },
                    scrollable: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "OrderID", width: "70px" },
                        { field: "ShipCountry", title:"Ship Country", width: "110px" },
                        { field: "ShipAddress", title:"Ship Address" },
                        { field: "ShipName", title: "Ship Name", width: "300px" }
                    ]
                });
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click one of the detail row, I want to get all detail IDs in that row. Please help me how to achieve this. I want to get OrderIDs. I have tried several methods but I am not able to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: So you don't want to display that data at all? You just want to retrieve the IDs of the orders that would would normally appear in the nested grid in the detail row? If that is the case you don't even need to set a detail row in your grid. You should just do an Ajax call to get the filtered data you need.

Answer (score 0):

As @JonathanBuchanan says if you are not going to display the detailed Grid, there is no point in using it. Just need to load the data when a row is selected.

To do so you have to bind a function to `change` event handler that defines a DataSource and then when read process received data.

In your example, you should do:

```
var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...
    selectable: true,
    change : function(e) {
        // Get the item from the model corresponding to the selected row.
        var item = this.dataItem(this.select());
        // Load orders for an Employee
        loadOrdersByEmployeeId(item.EmployeeID);
    },
    ...
});
```

The function `loadOrdersByEmployeeId` looks like:

```
function loadOrdersByEmployeeId(employeeID) {
    // Define a DataSource that reads Orders for an Employee given its ID
    var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        filter: { field: "EmployeeID", operator: "eq", value: employeeID }
    });
    // Fetch data and 
    ds.fetch(function (data) {
        // Extract OrderID and save it in an array
        var orders = [];
        $.each(data.items, function (idx, elem) {
            orders[idx] = elem.OrderID;
        });
        // Display Orders
        alert("orders:" + JSON.stringify(orders));
    });
}
```

You can see this running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XsLbz/

Comment: Thanks guys I solved it using ajax call by passing ID.